# How To Synchronize Directories in two different external hard disks?

Tags: directory, file-copy, synchronization

I have few big folders "cosmo_sim_9", "cosmo_sim_10".... in one of my external hard disk, and a old copy of this on another external hard disk.

I want to Synchronize old directories with the new one(recursively), but without overwriting already existing files(for saving time).

How can I do this? My os is Fedora 20.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `rsync`:

```
rsync -a --ignore-existing cosmo_sim_9 /dest/disk/cosmo_sim_9
```

`--ignore-existing` will cause it to skip existing files on the destination, `-a` will make it recursive, preserving if possible permission/ownership/group/timestamp/links/special devices.

you can do it for all directories by using a bash `for` loop:

```
for dir in cosmo_sim_* ; do
rsync -a --ignore-existing "$dir" "/dest/disk/$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `rsync` can accomplish this. Based on the type of system you have, you will need to donwload it:

- `sudo yum install rsync` (RPM Based)
- `sudo apt-get install rsync` (Debian Based)

Then using this, here is the command you will need to use:

`rsync -a source destination`

Or

`rsync -r source destination`

Where `-r` stands for copying data recursively (but don’t preserve timestamps and permission while transferring data.

`-a` stands for archive mode, archive mode allows copying files recursively and it also preserves symbolic links, file permissions, user & group ownerships and timestamps